# A word to say I'm "full of expectations and impatient to see it"?

Tags: word-meaning, phrase-request, phrases, literature

When I watch series and I just "can't wait" until the next episode, is it OK to say "I'm stretched how it's going to end"?

A simple translation from google gives me *tight* and *uptight*.

Answer (score 1):

To be honest, I don't think that's very idiomatic. You could, however, say something like this:

> I'm really **dying to know** how it's gonna end.

In my opinion, the expression [**dying to know**](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/dying+to+know) fits your situation just perfectly. You say that you're dying to know something when you can't wait to learn how an event or a situation is going to play out, weather it be in a movie, something about your friends or something at work.

Answer (score 1):

There are so many words in English that it is natural that people expect every complex idea to be expressible in a single word.

Unfortunately that is not a realistic expectation. "I am eager to see how it turns out" expresses the fact, but it does not sound dramatic. Most people want their lives to seem dramatic and so frequently resort to exaggerated or figurative language like "I'm literally dying to see how it turns out."